# Overwriting UrlHelper with a CustomUrlHelper - ASP.NET CORE 2.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

Is there a way to force my ASP.NET Core 2.0 app to use a custom UrlHelper I've written everywhere?

I have a class with custom logic

```
public class CustomUrlHelper : UrlHelper { ... }
```

I want it to be used everywhere, so that urls are generated according to our custom business rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `CustomUrlHelper` and a `CustomUrlHelperFactory`.

```
public class CustomUrlHelper : UrlHelper
{
    public CustomUrlHelper(ActionContext actionContext)
        : base(actionContext) { }

    public override string Action(UrlActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var controller = actionContext.Controller;
        var action = actionContext.Action;
        return $"You wrote {controller} > {action}.";
    }    
}

public class CustomUrlHelperFactory : IUrlHelperFactory
{
    public IUrlHelper GetUrlHelper(ActionContext context)
    {
        return new CustomUrlHelper(context);
    }
}
```

Then open your `Statup.cs` file and register the `CustomUrlHelperFactory` in the  `ConfigureServices` method.

```
services.AddMvc();

services.AddSingleton<IUrlHelperFactory, CustomUrlHelperFactory>();
```

After doing that, your app will use the `CustomUrlHelper` everywhere. That includes calls to `@Url.Action("Index", "Home")` from a razor page.